# Error when redirecting to index.php in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am through .htaccess redirecting my domain to a subfolder in my public_html folder like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.com/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomain.com/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mydomain.com/php [L]
```

When writing mydomain.com/index.php everything just works fine but if i leave out the index.php and just writes mydomain.co I get an 404 error?!?

What am i missing?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `^(.*)$` pattern to `^(.+)$`.

Or, switch the order of your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the trailing slash from

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.com/
```

To make it

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.com
```

?

Comment: When removing the slash it goes to the index.php but makes my url look like this: mydomain.com/mydomain.com/